# Neural network inputs transformation

Tags: r, neural-network

im trying to implement a neural network with the following data. I have already decided to transform my output variable to 0-1 and use a logistic activation function. The question is how to transform the input variables?
I have read that commonly we transform them either to 0/1 or -1/1 and use either logistic or tanh hidden notes transformation function. But i als read that some transform the input data to dummies ie. (1,2,3) or even not transform at all. Im kind of puzzled what is optimal to do. A second question concerning this matter is how to choice the hidden nodes activation function, is this based on the data transfomrmation?

thank you
S.

```
      Age   Salary Mortrate Clientrate Savrate PartialPrate
 [1,]  62 2381.140    0.047       7.05     3.1            0
 [2,]  52 1777.970    0.047       6.10     3.1            0
 [3,]  53 2701.210    0.047       6.40     3.1            0
 [4,]  52 4039.460    0.047       7.00     3.1            0
 [5,]  56  602.240    0.047       6.20     3.1            0
 [6,]  43 2951.090    0.047       6.80     3.1            0
 [7,]  49 4648.860    0.047       7.50     3.1            0
 [8,]  44 3304.110    0.047       7.10     3.1            0
 [9,]  56 1300.000    0.047       6.10     3.1            0
[10,]  50 1761.440    0.047       6.95     3.1            0
[11,]  63 1365.660    0.047       6.40     3.1            0
[12,]  51  986.530    0.047       6.40     3.1            0
[13,]  81    0.000    0.047       8.10     3.1            0
[14,]  64    0.000    0.047       5.80     3.1          697
[15,]  73    0.000    0.047       6.90     3.1          197
[16,]  56  226.890    0.047       5.15     3.1          750
[17,]  51 2576.645    0.047       3.70     3.1         8207
[18,]  66 3246.710    0.047       4.30     3.1            4
[19,]  66 3105.950    0.047       4.50     3.1         2998
[20,]  64  114.950    0.047       6.60     3.1          500
[21,]  84 1468.030    0.047       4.30     3.1         5000
[22,]  55 2616.510    0.047       4.70     3.1         3629
[23,]  71 3189.680    0.047       5.90     3.1         5445
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this great and vast neural network knowledge repository:

ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html

Normalization is theoretically not needed, as it can be achieved by other values of input weights. However in practice it is a good idea - otherwise during learning you are likely to stumble upon arithmetic overflow in neuron weights. Is range [0;1] better than [-1;1] is a tricky question which needs diving into very detailed analysis of your data set, and your learning algorithm.

Please refer to ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_std.

Answer (score 0):

It is often a good idea to transform an input vector to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one. This works well for statistical classifiers and for back propagation neural networks. it helps to make the clusters in feature space more evenly shaped (nearer to n-dimensional spheres). Having said that, the learning process in a multilayer neural network should adapt to whatever the input ranges happen to be so it is not a huge issue.
You have to use a non-linear (usually sigmoid) activation function for a multilayer network or it becomes equivalent to a single layer and will not learn complex boundary shapes between classes.

Comment: Yes i agree what you said, and this is precisely what i have read in most literature. But what im wondering is more why the choice of transformating to mean zeros standard deviation 1 and not the dummies 1,2,3 dividing them in intervals. And why use a sigmoid function? i have only read it is common to use sigmoid function because it adds non-linearity. does is even matter which to choice as long it is bounded and differentialble?

Comment: The issue is that the learning rule differentiates the function and this would always give a constant value for a linear transfer function. Any combination of linear transforms can be replaced by a single linear transform so multilayer nets do not do their magic without a sigmoid or atan-like funtion.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I agree to use the activation function you mentioned. But i still dont clearly understand what to do on the data transformation front? When do we standardize, when normalize, when catagorize. thanks in advance